# Where is the source of the Result type

Tags: f#

I want implement the Result (and the Option too) type in a language, so I should see the source in GitHub (F# is open source). But no, in GitHub isn't the implementation, only some functions.

Result type: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/result.fs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source is located in prim-types